# How to make stationary background view in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, background, scroll

I'm trying to add a view behind my grouped UITableView.  Unfortunately, whenever I scroll, the background view moves as well.  This happens even when I use [self.view insertSubview:backgroundView belowSubview:_tableView], or [_tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView].  Why is this background view scrolling?  Also, why does my tableView scroll, even though I have disabled scrolling?  Are these related?

In app Delegate:

```
    History *historyController = [[History alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:historyController];
```

In History.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    [_tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [bg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CenterFade.png"]];
    iv.alpha = .750;
    [bg addSubview:iv];
    [iv release]; iv = nil;

    [self.view addSubview:bg];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    [bg release]; bg = nil;
    [_tableView release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening, but for some reason self.view is a UITableView and not a UIView.  Creating a new UIView and setting it to self.view fixed the problem.  I am not using a UITableViewController, but a UIViewController.  No idea where the UITableView is coming from!

Comment: I ended up deleting the app from the simulator, and when I ran again this problem was gone.  Looks like it was some kind of bug where something was not getting updated, in spite of repeatedly cleaning and rebuilding. (I had changed from a UITableViewController to UIViewController).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [bg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CenterFade.png"]];
    iv.alpha = .750;
    [bg addSubview:iv];
    [iv release];
    iv = nil;

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    [_tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    [bg addSubview:_tableView];
    [_tableView release];
    _tableView = nil;
    [self.view addSubview:bg];
    [bg release];
    bg = nil;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

If your controller is an `UITableViewController` just change it to an `UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>` with a `tableView` property (It's the same)

Comment: I don't understand at all why, but even after adding the tableview to the background view, the background view is still scrolling up and down.  This is making me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

set `[_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

and then put your background view under UITableView in UIViewController view hierarchy.

Comment: That won't work because I am setting the background color to a pattern (though I suppose I could have used a third view and set the background pattern on that). Also, it is already beneath the UITableView.  Why would you need to set a clear background color on the background anyways?

Comment: You could set table background pattern to any view background. And when your table have transparent background you're free to draw any views and controls under it. I don't see reason for that, buy you could, if it's required.

Answer (score 0):

[`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html) has a [`backgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView) property.

Swift:

```
var backgroundView: UIView?
```

Objective-C

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *backgroundView
```

This view will not be moved when you scroll the tableView